# React Native touchableOpacity on android borderRadius cant work

Tags: javascript, react-native

I use a border radius in style to the button, the style is displayed correctly, however, clicking on the area of the cropped radius continues to work.

Here is an example of my implementation.

```
<View style={Style.userCircleContainerParent}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={Style.userCircleContainer} onPress={() => this.onAvatarClick()}>
        {this.props.state.pictureUrl
          ? <Image source={{uri: this.props.state.pictureUrl}} style={Style.userCircleImage} />
          : <Image source={loadingImage} style={Style.userCircleImage} />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Styles

```
  userCircleContainerParent: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: userIconSize,
    width: userIconSize,
    borderRadius: userIconSize / 2,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },

  userCircleContainer: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: userIconSize,
    width: userIconSize,
    borderRadius: userIconSize / 2,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },

  userCircleImage: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: userIconSize - 5,
    width: userIconSize - 5,
    marginTop: 2.5,
    borderRadius: (userIconSize - 5) / 2,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
```

Image
[active click area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxaqs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add this prop to the first view

```
pointerEvents = {'box-none'}
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents

Comment: the same story...
The problem is that to the TouchableOpacity remained square, and no matter what it is inside the view, it catches events outside the corners of the radius...